# issue in json array length and recyclerview

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I'm getting json datas and pass it to Recyclerview. My recyclerview sholud be 2 rows and 2 rows (totally 4 items). But my json datas are more than this. So I have limited the json datas by following code (parsing by AsyncTask).

```
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); 
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONObject product = object.getJSONObject("Products");
  Album item = new Album();
  item.setName(product.getString("pname"));
  item.setPrice(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(product.getDouble("pprice"))));
  display_deals_of_the_day.add(item);
}
```

In recyclerview, column count is properly working. But row count is exceeding sometimes (not all the times). Can anyone help to solve this issue. My recyclerview code is mentioned below.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(1), true));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Comment: You need to show your adapter code

Comment: what if the `JSONArray` has 3 items?